# Visual Studio 2022 - No html code hints in .cshtml file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

after installing VS2022 I have no longer auto completing html tags in cshtml file. Its really annoying that after typing for example html and pressing tab, entire  tag is not creating by itself. I remember I set it up in VS19 two years ago, but cant figure out how I did it. How can I fix it?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW7mk.png)

Comment: Question: if you start typing `<div class="mySillyClass" > random text </div>` does it figure it out?

Comment: Html tags are highlighted properly, but still pressing tab does nothing but inserting tab. https://imgur.com/a/SAHFwfC

Comment: Intellisense definitely turned on?